# verify if a outlook ribbon control is enabled or not

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I am working on outlook add ins. I have to check if outlook ribbon  button (idmso = "EncryptMessage") is enabled or not.

I tried to solve by using commandbars.GetEnabledMso("idmso")

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff862202(v=office.14).aspx

but for outlook the real challenge I am facing is to get command bars object.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865324(v=office.14).aspx

Please let me know the solution to resolve the issue.

Comment: I don't think Outlook 2010/2013 have an "Encrypt Message:" ribbon button. Where do you see it on the ribbon?

Comment: in outlook click on new email. Compose mail window will open. In option tab encrypt button is available. its a toggle button and its id is EncryptMessage.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Accessibility API to find the button on the Inspector ribbon and check if it is enabled.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am its author), it exposes the ribbon and its control though the [SafeInspector](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/SafeInspector.htm) object

```
set sInspector = CreateObject("Redemption.SafeInspector")
sInspector.Item = Application.ActiveInspector
set Ribbon =  sInspector.Ribbon
oldActiveTab = Ribbon.ActiveTab
Ribbon.ActiveTab = "Options"
set Control = Ribbon.Controls("Encrypt")
MsgBox Control.Enabled
Ribbon.ActiveTab = oldActiveTab 'restore the active tab
```